# How to make any file and put contents in that using script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to modify `configure.sh` to create a file `/etc/pam.d/XXX` with some predefined content.

How can I do this by putting the file's absolute path and content in configure.sh?

Please explain the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use here documents:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat > /etc/pam.d/XXX << 'EOF'
Place whatever
should go in
the file here
EOF

chown root:root /etc/pam.d/XXX  # Or whatever floats your boat
chmod u=r,go= /etc/pam.d/XXX    # Ditto
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the content, it would be best to put that in a separate file and just `cp` or `install` the file to `\etc\pam.d\XXX`. That way you avoid any problems related to escaping data within shell scripts. For example, to create a file only readable by root:

```
install --owner=root --group=root --mode='u=r' my_file /etc/pam.d/XXX
```

Note that on Unix and Linux systems, paths are always separated by slashes (`/`), *not* backslashes.